# What is the difference between destroy() and unpersist()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark is shipped with Broadcast variables, which allows us to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.

Of course, when the "broadcasted variable" isn't going to be used anymore, it is natural to delete this variable. But [from the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast), it seems that there's two way of deleting broadcasted variables which are:

```
unpersist() //Destroy all data and metadata related to this broadcast variable.
destroy() //Asynchronously delete cached copies of this broadcast on the executors.
```

I am not sure to properly understand everything, does unpersist() does the same as delete() but synchronously? This is unclear for me.

Answer (score 11):

As it is implemented in the two currently available concrete implementations ([`HttpBroadcast`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/HttpBroadcast.scala) and [`TorrentBroadacst`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/broadcast/TorrentBroadcast.scala)) there are two differences:

- `destroy` is blocking ([awaits for confirmation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManagerMaster.scala#L127)) while `unpersist` is by default non-blocking
- `destroy` removes persisted blocks from the `driver` while `unpersist` doesn't

Otherwise these use the same logic of the `BlockMangerMaster`.